# fluentd error hostname is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder

Tags: fluentd

I am trying to setup EFK stack and our environment is as below

```
(a)  ElasticSearch and Kibana runs on Windows machine
(b)  FluentD runs on CentOS
```

I am able to setup EFK and send logs to ElasticSearch and view it in Kibana successfully with default fluent.conf

However, I would like to create indexes using the format `${record['kubernetes']['pod_name']}` and I created a ConfigMap as follows

```
@include "#{ENV['FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF'] || 'systemd'}.conf"
@include "#{ENV['FLUENTD_PROMETHEUS_CONF'] || 'prometheus'}.conf"
#@include kubernetes.conf
#@include kubernetes/*.conf

   <match fluent.**>
        # this tells fluentd to not output its log on stdout
        @type null
    </match>
    # here we read the logs from Docker's containers and parse them
    <source>
      @type tail
      path /var/log/containers/*.log
      pos_file /var/log/containers.log.pos
      tag kubernetes.*
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
        @type json
        time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      </parse>
    </source>
    # we use kubernetes metadata plugin to add metadatas to the log
    <filter kubernetes.**>
        @type kubernetes_metadata
    </filter>
    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**kube-logging**.log>
    @type null
    </match>
    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**kube-system**.log>
    @type null
    </match>
    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**monitoring**.log>
    @type null
    </match>
    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**infra**.log>
    @type null
    </match>
     # we send the logs to Elasticsearch
    <match kubernetes.**>
       @type elasticsearch_dynamic
       @id out_es
       @log_level debug
       include_tag_key true
       host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
       port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
       scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
       reload_connections true
       logstash_format true
       logstash_prefix ${record['kubernetes']['pod_name']}
       <buffer>
           @type file
           path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/kubernetes.system.buffer
           flush_mode interval
           retry_type exponential_backoff
           flush_thread_count 2
           flush_interval 5s
           retry_forever true
           retry_max_interval 30
           chunk_limit_size 2M
           queue_limit_length 32
           overflow_action block
       </buffer>
    </match>
```

However, with my own `fluent.conf` it failed with the following error message

**Error Message**

```
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'host 192.xxx.xx.xxx' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'host: 192.xxx.xx.xxx' doesn't have tag placeholder
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'index_name fluentd' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'index_name: fluentd' doesn't have tag placeholder
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'template_name ' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'template_name: ' doesn't have tag placeholder
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'logstash_prefix index-%Y.%m.%d' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'logstash_prefix: index-%Y.%m.%d' has timestamp placeholders, but chunk key 'time' is not configured
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'logstash_prefix index-%Y.%m.%d' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'logstash_prefix: index-%Y.%m.%d' doesn't have tag placeholder
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'logstash_dateformat %Y.%m.%d' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'logstash_dateformat: %Y.%m.%d' has timestamp placeholders, but chunk key 'time' is not configured
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'logstash_dateformat %Y.%m.%d' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'logstash_dateformat: %Y.%m.%d' doesn't have tag placeholder
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'deflector_alias ' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'deflector_alias: ' doesn't have tag placeholder
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'application_name default' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'application_name: default' doesn't have tag placeholder
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] 'ilm_policy_id logstash-policy' is tested built-in placeholder(s) but there is no valid placeholder(s). error: Parameter 'ilm_policy_id: logstash-policy' doesn't have tag placeholder
2022-03-03 11:23:59 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] Need substitution: false
```

I tried suggestions googling however I am not sure what's missing in the config file.  Any help is highly appreciated